How to show Hausdorff measure $H^d$ is an outer measure?
The main deal is to show that countable subadditivity. For any sequence $C_n$ in a metric space $X$ I am able to show that $H^{d}_{\delta}(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n)\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} H^{d}_{\delta}(C_n)$. Now how to prove that $H^d=\lim_{\delta\to 0} H^{d}_{\delta}$ satisfy the same? I need some infinite sum limit interchange argument but I am not sure since this series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} H^{d}_{\delta}(C_n)$ converges uniformly in $\delta$ or not is questionable?

Limit as $\delta \to 0$ is also equal to supremum over $\delta$ . So $H^{d}{\delta}(\cup{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n)\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} H^{d}(C_n)$ for any $\delta >0$.

Ooh yes, this is an decreasing function over delta, that's why?@geetha290krm

@geetha290krm oh i recall since this is a decreasing function ovr delta that's why right? So, $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} H^{d}{\delta} (C_i)\leq\sum{i=0}^{\infty} H^d(C_i)$.

Yes, that is correct.
